# Github Actionで Buildozerの実行エラー

Tags: python, github-actions, cython

【問題内容】
Github Actionで Buildozerの実行でエラーが発生します。

```
[DEBUG]:    running build_ext
[DEBUG]:    building 'jnius' extension
[DEBUG]:    /usr/bin/ccache /github/workspace/.buildozer_global/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -I/github/workspace/.buildozer_global/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/un_official_launcher/armeabi-v7a/include/python3.1 -fPIC -I/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/jnius/jnius.o
[DEBUG]:    jnius/jnius.c:12406:19: warning: assigning to 'jchar *' (aka 'unsigned short *') from 'const jchar *' (aka 'const unsigned short *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
[DEBUG]:      __pyx_v_j_chars = (__pyx_v_j_env[0])->GetStringChars(__pyx_v_j_env, __pyx_v_j_string, NULL);
[DEBUG]:                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[DEBUG]:    jnius/jnius.c:54433:5: error: expression is not assignable
[DEBUG]:        ++Py_REFCNT(o);
[DEBUG]:        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
[DEBUG]:    jnius/jnius.c:54435:5: error: expression is not assignable
[DEBUG]:        --Py_REFCNT(o);
[DEBUG]:        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

数か月前までエラーが無かったブランチです。

【試行】
以下サイトを参考に、

https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#error-expression-is-not-assignable

・Cython のアップグレード は、
　　requirements = kivy, android, cython==0.29.33
や
　　requirements = kivy, android, cython
として

・p4a.branch = develop

もしてみましたが、解決はしません。

ただ、buildozer appclean については、
Github Action での実行方法が不明で行っておりません。

また、現在 fork元の以下も、自動実行でエラーが出ておりますので

https://github.com/kivy/kivy-launcher/actions

これも参考になりません。

【お願い】
何方かアドバイスをいただけますか？
宜しくお願いします。